# React Callback Results

Tags: reactjs, callback, render, timing

I have a component that checks for unique codes in my SQL backend. It works great.
What is the correct react syntax to call the code when I need it, right after I press the Save button and before I update the SQL database (providing the returned code is unique).

Currently the VerifySiteCodeComponent only gets called on the initial render. How do I move the call to inside the saveCpyMaster routine or force it to run when I press the Save button?

I have included the code for the VerifySiteCodeComponent for added clarity and possible aid in a solution.

Probably a simple solution for someone, just not me. Still new to the React world.  @davidsz - any ideas

...

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import VerifySiteCodeComponent from './VerifySiteCodeComponent';
    
    class ParentComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                cpymasterid:13,
                sitemasterCode:'AZ302',
                uniquehere:true,
                answer:'not yet'
            }
            this.changeUnique = this.changeUnique.bind(this);
        }
          
        componentDidMount(){
        }
    
        changeUnique = (unique) =>{
            this.setState({uniquehere: unique})
            if (this.state.uniquehere)
            {
                this.setState({answer:"True"})
            } else {
                this.setState({answer:"False"})
            }
        }
    
        saveCpyMaster(){
            //Need result from <VerifySiteCodeComponent> here
            //after data entry and before I update the SQL file.
            //How do I do that?
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.saveCpyMaster}>Save</button>
                    <VerifySiteCodeComponent onUpdate={this.changeUnique} cpymasterid={this.state.cpymasterid} sitemasterCode={this.state.sitemasterCode}/>  
                    {this.state.answer}
                    {this.state.cpymasterid}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default ParentComponent

import { Component } from 'react';
import SiteMasterService from '../Services/SiteMasterService'
//-------------
class VerifySiteCodeComponent extends Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            unique:true,
            check_cpymasterid: this.props.cpymasterid,
            check_sitemasterCode: this.props.sitemasterCode
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        SiteMasterService.getSiteMastersByCode(this.state.check_sitemasterCode).then((res) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) 
        {
            if (parseInt(res.data[i].cpymaster_cpymasterId,10) === this.state.check_cpymasterid )
            {
                this.setState({unique:false})
            }
        }
        this.props.onUpdate(this.state.unique)
    });
     
    }
    render() {
        return this.state.unique;
    }
}
export default VerifySiteCodeComponent;
```

...

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a component to render this functionality versus just making it a function call that you can then use in a lifecycle method/on click? Does the component actually render any JSX?

Comment: Great question. I am good at coding components, functions mess me up, I get all these errors.  I added the VerifySiteCodeComponent code in the original question for clarity, it does not need to render anything, just update the 'uniquehere' variable so I can use it to make sure I am not updating my SQL with duplicate codes. I  need to be able to make this happen when I hit the Save button and before the code in  saveCpyMaster executes.  Any help understanding how to get around this chicken or egg thing would be great as I need to understand the solution to this React for other issues.@Dylan Lee

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logic in your VerifySiteCodeComponent it probably should not be it's own component. I would move the logic into a utility function and pass in the variables you are holding in it's state as function arguments. So something like

```
export function verify_code(check_code, check_id, change_unique){
   let unique = true; 
   SiteMasterService.getSiteMastersByCode(check_code).then((res) => {
        for (let i=0; i<res.data.length; i++) {
            if (parseInt(res.data[i].cpymaster_cpymasterId,10) === check_id){
                unique = false;
            }
        }
        change_unique(this.state.unique)
        return unique
}
```

This would then allow you to import and call the function on componentDidMount if need be, as well as in the onclick handler saveCPYMaster.

Take a look at this resource for building external utility files. It may help you with the errors you're running into with functions.  https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/importing-utility-functions-in-reactjs

Answer (score -1):

I can't explain it perfect(because i don't work with class components a lot) but i think that you need to use arrow functions or "bind" for that onClick.

try to make this:

```
saveCpyMaster = () => {
your code here...
}
```

and make that onClick like this `onClick = {()=>this.saveCpyMaster()}`

i think it will help and solve your problem but you should read about arrow functions and bind(i realize that i need to read mroe too XD)

Comment: I do enjoy using arrow functions, but this does not really solve the problem, arrow functions are syntactical sugar on top of regular functions. His error is not related to calling the on-click, but with how to get the code refactored into the correct place. Bind is only needed if you are attempting to use 'this' within the function you are calling. Please check out this documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html